# cache images details

Tags: javascript, image, caching

Do I need cache image details for images that are being resized multiple times very quickly.  I was checking out chrome developers tools timeline and I noticed that Image Decode-details and Image Resize(where image details were also cached) both took over 250 ms in duration the first time the image resized and about 18ms every time after.    Should I manually cache details.  Am I even reading this right?

[image]

Comment: How would you do this if you could?

Comment: User clicks button to scale iframe and Image contained inside up or down.

Comment: I can't see script to swap images to "cache' them would be any faster than the natively resizing the same image.

Comment: when i resize image "Image Decode details" runs first followed by "Image Resize - details"  with a message of "details cached.  I'm not saying that the image itself is being cached.  Just reading back from chrome timeline screen.